# Calling a void function to add two numbers then dealing with the pointer of the sum

Tags: c

My objective is to call a void function "sum" which is passed two integers where they will be added together. I then want the first integer variable to be modified so that it is pointing at the sum of the two integers.

When I compile I get "error: indirection requires pointer operand ('int' invalid)."

Comment: @AntonH: why did you delete your answer?

Comment: @AntonH: Thank you for the advice, I'm fairly new to the concept. I just figured I would ask on stack to see how far off I am.

Comment: @chqrlie I'm always paranoid about pointers, so put the answer, then got worried and wanted to test first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
void sum(int *x, int y){
    *x += y; // *x means "contents of what is pointed to by pointer x"
}

void call_sum() {
    int x = 1, y = 2;

    sum(&x,y); // &x because you're passing the address

    printf("%d\n", x); // this should print 3
}
```

Comment: Okay I was pretty far off on the concept, thanks a bunch I understand completely now!

Comment: @cmsp Glad to help :)

Answer (score 2):

In that case you want:

```
void sum ( int * x, int y ) {
     if (x != NULL) *x += y;
}
  ...
sum(&x, y);
```

Saying `int * y` says you need to pass the address of an int variable. The `&` character is the `address-of` operator.

In the function `*y` says use the value at the address, not the address itself.

The `if (x != NULL)` check is because, without it doing:

```
sum(NULL, x);
```

is "undefined behavior" (think Allstate "Mayhem" commercial) :)

Comment: I don't think OP is ready for assert, but we could certainly prefix that with `if (x != NULL)`

Comment: Thank you also for expanding @JohnHascall